# Working with Flask-Script and cron jobs

Tags: heroku, cron, flask, external-script

So I've been meaning to create a cron job on my prototype Flask app running on Heroku. Searching the web I found that the best way is by using Flask-Script but I fail to see the point of using it. Do I get easier access to my app logic and storage info? And if I do use Flask-Script, how do I organize it around my app? I'm using it right now to start my server without really knowing the benefits. My folder structure is like this:

```
/app
   /manage.py
   /flask_prototype
      all my Flask code
```

Should I put the 'script.py' to be run by the Heroku Scheduler on app folder, the same level as manage.py? If so, do I get access to the models defined within flask_prototype?

Thank you for any info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-Script just provides a framework under which you can create your script(s). It does not give you any better access to the application than what you can obtain when you write a standalone script. But it handles a few mundane tasks for you, like command line arguments and help output. It also folds all of your scripts into a single, consistent command line master script (this is `manage.py`, in case it isn't clear).

As far as where to put the script, it does not really matter. As long as `manage.py` can import it and register it with Flask-Script, and that your script can import what it needs from the application you should be fine.